# NMinimize error: Nearest::neard:

Tags: warning-messages, mathematical-optimization

I have this function GuessError, here's a plot assuming a single variable x, `Plot[GuessError[10^x, etc..], {x, 8, 12}]` , being etc some more variables which are previously defined, machine-type numbers.
[image: plot of my function, which has a minimum in the given range]

It shows that minimum near x=9.

Now if I try `NMinimize[{GuessError[10^x, etc..], {8.8 < x < 9.2}}, x]`, I get this error message:

```
Nearest::neard: "The default distance function does not give a real numeric distance when applied to the point pair Max[0.23359984866812222`,-(3.23*10^15\10^-x)/(1+<<23>>\10^(<<5>><<1>><<1>>]))^0.5+ ..."
```

It does not have to do with `Real` or `Complex` values, because my function returns always `Abs[...]`. What could be the problem here?

Here is the function, in the minimization, I use `ni = 10^x`:

```
GuessError[IVcurve_,Area_,ni_,mue_,krec_,Jgen_,d_,T_]:=Module[{Vext,q,Vt,Jsim,Vexp,Vsup,Vinf,ninf,nsup,Jexp,Jrange,Vrange,Iexp,Vint,imin,imax,JV},
  Vt = 8.61733238 10^-5 (T + 273.15);
  q = 1.6 10^-19;
  Iexp = Transpose[IVcurve][[2]]/Area;
  Vexp = Transpose[IVcurve][[1]];
  Jexp = Iexp/Area;
  Vint = Vt Log[(Jexp + Jgen)/(q d krec ni^2) + 1]; 
  Vext = Vint + (d Jexp)/(2 q mue ni E^(Vint/(2 Vt)));
  Vinf = Max[First[Vext], First[Vexp]]; 
  ninf = Flatten[Position[Vexp, Nearest[Vexp, Vinf][[1]]]][[1]];
  Vsup = Min[Last[Vext], Last[Vexp]]; 
  nsup = Flatten[Position[Vexp, Nearest[Vexp, Vsup][[1]]]][[1]];

  Vrange = Take[Vext, {ninf, nsup}];

      Abs@Total[(Vrange - Take[Vexp, {ninf, nsup}])^2]]
```

Comment: What is `GuessError[ ]`?

Comment: Problems with code usually require the code.  My guess is that it's a [`_?NumericQ` problem](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037).

Comment: ok I included it in the original question. The point is that it evaluates to real numbers. If I try an `Interpolation` of a table of my function as a function of x, `NMinimize` works.

Comment: I think that it would be more helpful to have the *code* for `GuessError`, rather than its plot.

Comment: My (guessed) point is that `GuessError[.., .., 10^x, etc.]` does not itself evaluate to a number at all.  (Try `GuessError[Table[{t, 10^t + RandomReal[]}, {t, 10}], 1, 10^x, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`.)

Comment: This is still not really enough to reproduce the error. You should include the exact phrasing of the `GuessError` call (including the values of everything in `etc`) that will produce the error.

Comment: Michael, you didnt give x a value. Try with some x and it will evaluate to a real number.

Comment: @Kurt, You didn't give `x` a value either. "`NMinimize[{GuessError[10^x, etc..],...`"  [`NMinimize` will evaluate it's argument symbolically in order to construct a Jacobian/Hessian.]

Comment: @Michael, wait, x is the variable, why should I do so? `NMinimize[x^2, x]` doesn't require me to give an explicit value of x

Comment: Evaluating `x^2` does not produce an error message.

Comment: @Michael, thanks for your help, I guess if `NMinimize` is always trying to obtain an analytical Jacobian, it won't work in my particular case. Now my question is, does `NMinimize` have any method that does not rely on analytical evaluations?

Comment: Yes, it works either way.  It's just the more info, the faster it can find the solution usually.  -  See my update.  Let me know if I messed something up.

Comment: See the tutorial http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical.html for information about the methods available to `NMinimize`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is enough information in the question to make a confident guess at the problem.  The key clue is in the quoted error message:

> Nearest::neard: "The default distance function does not give a real numeric distance when applied to the point pair Max[0.23359984866812222`,-(3.23*10^15\10^-x)/(1+<<23>>\10^(<<5>><<1>><<1>>]))^0.5+ ..."

We can see that there is a `10^x` in the message, which shows that the call to `GuessError[.., .., 10^x, etc.]` was evaluated with a symbolic `x`.  ([`NMinimize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMinimize.html) is not [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html) or [`HoldFirst`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldFirst.html).)  This is a classic problem solved by `_?NumericQ`, which is explained in this answer: [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037)

Indeed both calls below yield a `Nearest::neard` error:

```
GuessError[Table[{t, 10^t}, {t, 10}], 1, 10^x, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
NMinimize[{GuessError[Table[{t, 10^t}, {t, 10}], 1, 10^x, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  {0.1 < x < 1.5}}, x]
```

The minimal fix is to add a `?NumericQ` to `ni`:

```
GuessError[IVcurve_, Area_, ni_?NumericQ, mue_, krec_, Jgen_, d_, T_] := ...
```

One might add it to other variables except `IVcurve`, which needs a `?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ]&)` [`PatternTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html).

---

*Gratuitous suggestions*

Since `NMinimize` can be slow, it might be good to speed up `GuessError`.  Depending on how large `IVcurve` is, since it is static, it would be potentially much faster to construct the `NearestFunction` just once for the optimization problem.

Next, since it is the position of the nearest point that is desired, it will be more efficient to use the form

```
Nearest[Vexp -> Automatic]
```

These two changes speed up `NMinimize` 35% in a test run on an `IVcurve` of length `1000`, 20% on a curve of length `100`.

Further, one can do some more of the construction of the objective function by precomputing `Jexp` and `Vexp` which are constant (with respect to `ni`).  With these improvements, the same optimization runs almost 65% faster on a curve of length 1000 (and almost 50% faster on a curve of length 100).

Code:

```
ClearAll[GuessError, objGuessError];
 (* No pattern tests - Returns an objective function, objGuessError *)
GuessError[IVcurve_, Area_, ni_, mue_, krec_, Jgen_, d_, T_] :=
 objGuessError[
  IVcurve[[All, 1]]/Area^2, IVcurve[[All, 2]],
  Nearest[IVcurve[[All, 1]] -> Automatic],
  Area, ni, mue, krec, Jgen, d, T]; 

objGuessError[Jexp_, Vexp_, iNF_, Area_, ni_?NumericQ, mue_, krec_, Jgen_, d_, T_] := 
 Module[{Vext, q, Vt, Jsim, Vsup, Vinf, ninf, nsup, Jrange, Vrange, 
   Vint, imin, imax, JV}, Vt = 8.61733238 10^-5 (T + 273.15);
  q = 1.6 10^-19;
  Vint = Vt Log[(Jexp + Jgen)/(q d krec ni^2) + 1];
  Vext = Vint + (d Jexp)/(2 q mue ni E^(Vint/(2 Vt)));
  Vinf = Max[First[Vext], First[Vexp]];
  ninf = First[iNF[Vinf]];
  Vsup = Min[Last[Vext], Last[Vexp]];
  nsup = First[iNF[Vsup]];
  Vrange = Take[Vext, {ninf, nsup}];
  Abs@Total[(Vrange - Take[Vexp, {ninf, nsup}])^2]]
```

Example optimization:

```
ivcurve = Table[{t, 10^t}, {t, 0, 10, 0.01}];
NMinimize[{GuessError[ivcurve, 1, 10^x, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], {0.1 < x < 1.5}}, x]
```

Comment: Thank you @Michael E2, it works just as you say in the first part of your answer. I am still having trouble finding the minimum with actual values but thats another story. The ?NumberQ as pattern in the definition of the function buffles me, because somehow `NMinimize` "notices" and prevents evaluation, but it does not with a more simple function like x^2.

Comment: More of a hint than an explanation: First `ClearAll[f, g]; f[x_?NumericQ] := x^2; g[x_] := x^2`. Then consider `NMinimize[f[x], x]` vs. `NMinimize[g[x], x]`.  Now `f[x]` evaluates to `f[x]` - nothing happens because `NumericQ[x]` is `False`. This is the standard *Mathematica* evaluation and has nothing to with `NMinimize`. But `f[2]` yields `4`. OTOH, `g[x]` evaluates to the symbolic expression `x^2`. Execute the the `NMinimize` commands and you get different answers, because `NMinimize` has to use a finite difference approximation for `f'[x]`. See the links in the linked Q above for more.

Comment: If you're having trouble finding the minimum, you could consult the tutorial I linked in my last comment under the main question.  Another method or increasing `"MaxIterations"` may help.  Your graph looks ragged.  You can monitor the process with ``Block[{Optimization`NMinimizeDump`dbPrint = Print}, NMinimize[…]]``, but do it in its own notebook and be prepared for tons and tons of output.  If you do it on `f` or `g` in my previous comment, look for "Entering KKT" to see where the derivative comes into play.

Comment: Thank you Michael E2!! Really helps! I did take a look at your linked tutorial and found many useful things. I got the NMinimize working now and playing around with the Methods.